# How to model CRISPR/Cas9 binding and cleavage using a generalized Kittel's zipper model?

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-biology, statistical-mechanics, structural-biology, dna-rna

I am thinking about how to model the binding of a CRISPR/Cas9+[guide-RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guide_RNA) complex to a double-stranded DNA that cause its cleavage.

This [post](https://sites.tufts.edu/crispr/crispr-mechanism/rna-guide/) describes four steps at which a CRISPR/Cas9 system binds and cuts a target DNA strand:

1. PAM Binding:
2. Phosphate Lock Loop
3. Guide RNA binding
4. Cleavage

I believe it is possible to develop a fairly simple model based on [Kittel's zipper model](https://blog.cupcakephysics.com/thermodynamics%20and%20statistical%20physics/2015/09/20/the-molecular-zipper.html) or [its generalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0306354) to estimate the propensity of a Cas9 and gRNA to cleave the DNA.
Thus, I would appreciate some advice how to develop such a zipper-like model (e.g., maybe by having a double zipper).

Ultimately, I would like to compute the free energy of the different states based on the sgRNA sequence: $\Delta G_\text{bind}$, $\Delta G_\text{melt}$, $\Delta G_\text{cut}$.

Here is another schematic illustration by [Addgene](https://www.addgene.org/guides/crispr/) (in this illustration, the binding step includes the DNA melting and the binding of the RNA with the DNA):

[image]